# Are foreign traders subject to UK consumer law if they advertise services to UK residents?

Tags: united-kingdom, consumer-protection, advertisements

I am in several WhatsApp groups for offer holders for UK universities. There is an essay writing group which repeatedly sends messages advertising their services despite the messages being clearly unwanted by everyone in the group chats, and I've heard from other users that they are a scam. After some digging, I found that they aren't registered in any country but the person who seems to be in charge of the operation is living in Kenya. Would the essay writing service be subject to the UK's Consumer Protection from Unfair Trading Regulations? If not, is there any other law or regulation being broken here, either concerning the unsolicited advertising messages or the contract cheating itself?

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

However, criminals tend not to follow the law - that’s what makes them criminals.